# How to create AVPlayer Layer in tableView Cell from outside tableView func?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayerlayer

I am making an instagram-like app where I want to show a cover image for a video, then when the play button (on the image) is tapped, the video plays. I am able to create and show the posts as desired, however when I tap the play button, the video plays (I can hear the audio), but it's not visible.

I am trying to display the video in case 1: below

I am handling the play button function outside the tableView in an @bjc func.

I think my problem is setting the playerLayer.frame to the desired cell/view, but I'm not entirely sure. I would appreciate any help. Here's my code. Thanks!

UPDATED w/ SOLUTION:
Thanks to a nudge in the right direction I learned that to access the cell of the tableview I needed to use the sender property. In this case sender.superview gave me the view I was trying to access.

Code updated below with correction. Thanks for the help!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.section]

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostHeaderCell") as! PostHeaderCell
        cell.userProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: post.userPhotoURL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NinjaIcon"), options: [], completed: nil)
        cell.usernameLabel.text = post.username

        return cell

    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostImageCell") as! PostImageCell
        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: post.photoURL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "photo-7"), options: [], completed: nil)
        cell.playButton.isHidden = false 
        cell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlay), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.section


        return cell

    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostActionCell") as! PostActionCell
        cell.delegate = self
        configureCell(cell, with: post)

        return cell

    default:
        fatalError("Error: unexpected indexPath")
    }
}

@objc func handlePlay(sender: UIButton!) {

    let cell = sender.superview

    let tag = sender.tag
    let post = posts[tag]
    let text = post.postText
    let videoURLString = post.videoURL
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURLString!)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = cell.postImage.bounds
    cell.postImage.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player.play()

    // test to make sure the right video is playing
    print("for text: ",text)
    print("Attempting to Play: ",videoURLString )

}
```

Comment: Dequeueing a reusable cell outside of `cellForRowAt` won't do anything, it gives you a new cell that isn't added to the `tableView`. You need to get the associated cell utilizing `sender`.

Comment: I'm taking a stab in the dark, but have you might tried cell.bringSubviewToFront(cell.postImage).

Comment: @TomQDRS I tried using sender.imageView and it gave me the imageView of the playbutton, which was better than nothing, but pretty small to watch the video ;) How could I access the cell through the sender property?

Comment: @TomQDRS Got it! cell = sender.superview did the trick. Thank you!